# funny behaviour with tabNavigator

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml

I have a tabNavigator in my flex app. I am using: `tabNavigator.getTabAt(indx).y` to get the y-position of each tab.
For some odd reason the y-position comes out to be different for tabs that have visited by the user, as compared to un-visited ones.
I am using a creationpolicy = "all" on the tabNavigator.
Not sure why this is happening.
Any clues would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that sounds like a Flex bug.

Looking at the code for TabNavigator (and buttonBar) it looks like the drawButtonFocus function might be shifting the button on the bar slightly (in terms of measurement rather than actually moving it). That would certainly explain that behaviour.

If the same thing happens when you tab through the tabs, then it defenitely is a Flex bug, and you should add it to the Jira.